# String in Switch for both upper and lower case

Tags: java, switch-statement

In Switch case to take input for both upper and lower case is it correct as I have written below or is there any other better way.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class SwitchDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 'IN' or 'OUT': \n");
    String c = sc.nextLine();
    switch(c) {
         case "IN" :
              System.out.println("\nWelcome to My PC\n");
               break;
        case "OUT":
              System.out.println("\nGood Bye\n");
              break;
        case "in" :
              System.out.println("\nWelcome to My PC\n");
               break;
        case "out":
              System.out.println("\nGood Bye\n");
              break;
       default:
          System.out.println("\nInvalid input\n");
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is correct if you only want to accept `IN` or `in`, but not `In` or `iN`. Note that you can write cases together without a break, e.g. `case "IN": case "in": // Code to execute`, so you don't need to duplicate the code like this.

Comment: If you use `c = sc.nextLine();.toUpper()` then you only have to compare to upper case values.